# Read excel file hosted in remote server

Tags: excel, vba, server

I uploaded an Excel file to a server, the file is a small db.
I would like to read and write the file through another excele file using vba.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open the workbook you need using the following code (and close it). For as long as it is open you can work with it (and copy or paste data for example) regularly.

Just use for example:

```
Workbooks("New Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet").Range("A1:A2").Copy
```

Main code:

```
Sub OpenWorkbook()
'Open a workbook

  'Open method requires full file path to be referenced.
  Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\username\Documents\New Data.xlsx"

End Sub


Sub CloseWorkbook()
'Close a workbook

  Workbooks("New Data.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

For the connection to the FTP server, this code should help you out or give you an idea at least. Once again some tinkering may be needed.

```
Function FTP_Upload_File(QuellDatei As String, ZielDatei As String, FTPServer As String, FTPBenutzer As String, FTPKennwort As String) As Long
    Dim FTP             As Inet
    Dim ExecString      As String

    On Local Error GoTo FuncExit

    Set FTP = New Inet
    With FTP
        .Protocol = icFTP
        .RemoteHost = FTPServer
        .Username = FTPBenutzer
        .Password = FTPKennwort

        ExecString = "put " & Chr(34) & QuellDatei & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & ZielDatei & Chr(34)
        .Execute .URL, ExecString
        Do While .StillExecuting
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With

FuncExit:
    FTP_Upload_File = FTP.ResponseCode
    Set FTP = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I have opened the file but how can I save the changes in the server?

Comment: The` SaveChanges:=True` Paramter in the second sub should save all changes you made to the document.

Comment: Yes it saves the changes but locally then I want to upload the modified file to a ftp server, can you help me?

Comment: Thank, as soon as I try I'll let you know

Comment: Please upvote and Accept my answer if I could help you, It gives me sweet, sweet rep ;)